# CMS with built-in A/B testing

Tags: content-management-system

I would like to start trying new layouts and visuals on web pages that I manage. So far I am managing all my pages via scripts on my local machine and just upload static html files to a hosting machine; I am happy to set up almost any basic CMS or "static site manager".

What are some CMS (or a more basic platform for managing static html pages) that has built-in support for keeping track of multiple versions of a page and recording a user's flow from age to page?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does thas job very well. Also you can use "Google Content Experiments" (aka "Google Analytics Experiments") for FREE, and just add a link to two different versions of your page. For A/B testing google experiments is a PERFECT tool.
How to set-up an A/B experiment read here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745216